# what is the name of this optimization technique?

Tags: c++, for-loop, compiler-optimization

What is the name of below optimization technique and why it is better than previous implementation?

```
const int size = 100;
int arr1[size];
int arr2[size];
```

From double loop

```
for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
    arr1[i] = 1;

for(int i=0; i<size; ++i)
    arr2[i] = 1;
```

to single loop

```
for(int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
    arr1[i] = 1;
    arr2[i] = 1;
}
```

### Edit

Options are;

- Pointer aliasing
- Loop-invariant code motion
- Copy elison
- Loop fusion
- Loop unrolling

Comment: _Reducing redundant branch operations_ perhaps? Your code sample doesn't compile BTW.

Comment: btw I encountered it in an C++ test, I will share the options now

Comment: @DietmarKühl I believe the example is using “pseudo C” to explain a compiler-internal code transformation in a more human.readable way.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: You can only replace these loops with calls to `memset` if `sizeof(int)==1`. In a typical case, using `memset` will result in values of `0x01010101` instead of the desired `0x00000001`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia refers to this optimization as [*loop fusion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_fusion).  The idea is, that the loop control flow overhead is not doubled for the two loops.  This might not have the desired effect on performance if the combined loop has a poor memory access pattern but since both loops in your example are accessing contiguous blocks of memory in order, the hardware should be able to deal with it effectively.

Before the transformation, each of the loops does this:

1. Initialize `i` with 0.
2. Load the constant `size`.
3. If `i >= size`, jump to 8.
4. Load the address `arr1` where the array begins.
5. Store the constant 1 at the address `arr1 + i`.
6. Increment `i` by one.
7. Jump to 3.
8. End

And then immediately again:

9. Initialize `i` with 0.
10. Load the constant `size`.
11. If `i >= size`, jump to 16.
12. Load the address `arr2` where the array begins.
13. Store the constant 1 at the address `arr2 + i`.
14. Increment `i` by one.
15. Jump to 11.
16. End

The first thing any compiler would probably do is to move the “load the constant `size`” and “load the address `arr`” out of the loops body.  Yet the ratio of total work over useful work is not very good.  Compare this with the combined loop:

1. Initialize `i` with 0.
2. Load the constant `size`.
3. If `i >= size`, jump to 10.
4. Load the address `arr1` where the array begins.
5. Store the constant 1 at the address `arr1 + i`.
6. Load the address `arr2` where the array begins.
7. Store the constant 1 at the address `arr2 + i`.
8. Increment `i` by one.
9. Jump to 3.
10. End

Counting bullet points as a measure of machine instructions is not the most accurate way to reason about performance.  You'll need to know what instructions your actual hardware supports to actually compare the number of required instructions.

Comment: "If i >= size, jump to 9." Looks like a typo, shouldn't that be "jump to 8" ?

Comment: @tux3 Indeed, thanks.  The markdown renderer is helpfully correcting my typos on the jump labels without correcting my branching instructions… ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It is called [loop fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_fusion) (or loop jamming, as Wikipedia helpfully points out), and as you might understand it can happen anytime two adjacent loops iterate over the same range without cross-referencing each other.

Note that this doesn't always necessarily improve speed.

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like pessimization to me!

You are totally ruining the memory locality of the data accessed within the loop, and potentially causing a horrendous number of cache misses.

The only way to be sure is, of course, to measure it, but jumping to the conclusion that this is an "optimization", just because you only do half the number of increments and comparisons on `i`, is silly.

Comment: I think calling this “totally ruining” is a little exaggerated.  A modern cache should be able to handle iterating over two contiguous arrays in parallel.  If it were not, almost any linear algebra application, which heavily depend on efficient scalar products, would be in much trouble.

Comment: note that; total array size is so small so that data locality won't be problem here

Comment: @MuratKarakuş: You don't know that

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Admittedly it is my assumption that cache size will be more than at least 2KB. I don't think that this is unrealistic assumption. Even if int is 8 byte, total array size is 200 * 8 = 1600 byte. 1600 / 1024 =~ 1.5 kb. So it is reasonable, isn't it.

Comment: @MuratKarakuş: Maybe.